# Where to post question about understanding coding challenge?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

A few months ago I was randomly chosen for Google's 'foobar' challenge (a coding challenge that Google offers to random individuals based on coding related search history). I got through a few of the stages, but got to one I didn't understand. There was a time limit so I'm no longer able to submit an answer (i.e. this isn't a do my challenge for me sort of question), but I would still like to understand the challenge.

What I don't understand about the challenge is less how I would implement a solution in a coding language, but more what it is even asking me to do. This complicates my dilemma of figuring out where to post my question. <s>Would I just post it to Stack Overflow, and if so what tags would I use?</s> What site would be best for this kind of question?

Comment: So a good SO question contains enough code to replicate your problem.  I don’t see this question being well received at SO for that reason.

Comment: Yes I am mostly familiar with SO, that is why I didn't post it there before checking whether there was a better site.

Comment: see also: [Is there a less restrictive Stack Exchange site specially suited for not too specific questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252777/839601)